# SalesForce API Multipart message must include a non-binary part error

Tags: c#, salesforce, multipartform-data, restsharp

I tried  to create file in salesforce api but i got the this error

**[{"message":"Multipart message must include a non-binary part","errorCode":"INVALID_MULTIPART_REQUEST"}]**

Here is my code, i am using restsharp library

```
               var salesForceEmailrequest = CreateRequest("https://cs128.salesforce.com/services/data/v23.0/sobjects/ContentVersion", Method.POST);
    
                contentVersionRequest.First_Publish_Location_Id = response.Value.Id;

                string eFileDatajson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(contentVersionRequest.First_Publish_Location_Id);

                salesForceEmailrequest.AddParameter("entity_document", eFileDatajson);
                salesForceEmailrequest.AddFile("VersionData", contentVersionRequest.Content,"Email from  X", "message/rfc822");
                salesForceEmailrequest.AddHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
```

Have you ever encountered something like this? Any help is very much appreciated

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to build a `multipart/form-data` on the `requestbody` based on the specs: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_sobject_insert_update_blob.htm

```
--boundary_string
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="entity_content";
Content-Type: application/json

{"ContentLocation":"S","Title":"test","PathOnClient":"Test.txt"}

--boundary_string
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="VersionData"; filename="test.txt"

Here's a text file
Adding text to a text file

--boundary_string--
```